# simple code not working

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Login Page</title>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Optional theme -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4"></div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports" alt="Loading Logo...">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4"></div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

But the Body is upper than the window and has more space with left than right. Like this:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Flagged for being unclear. You didn't ask a question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to fit an image into a `column` that that the image itself is larger then. Depending on what you're ultimately trying to do there are several ways to fix this.

If you are simply trying to place an image in the center of the viewport you can apply the [img-responsive](https://getbootstrap.com/css/#images-responsive) class while using [column offsets](https://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting) (instead of empty columns on either side).

You can also do this without the grid by using the [center-block](https://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-center) class on the image.

Here are some examples that show your example code with the overflow of the column along with some solutions for centering the image.

**Working Examples:** *Run Code Snippet at FullPage*

```css
/*FOR DEMO ONLY*/

.row {
  background: #F8BBD0;
}
.col-md-4,
.col-xs-4,
.col-xs-12 {
  border: 4px solid #BF360C;
}
div img {
  border: 4px solid #212121;
}
/*FOR DEMO ONLY*/
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="text-center">IMAGE OVERFLOWING COLUMN</h1>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/400x200/FFF176/212121" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="text-center">COLUMN OFFSET</h1>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-4">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/400x200/880E4F/FFF" alt="" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="text-center">CENTER BLOCK</h1>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/400x200/880E4F/FFF" alt="" class="center-block img-responsive">
</div>
<hr>
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="text-center">CENTER BLOCK + COL-XS-12</h1>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/400x200/880E4F/FFF" alt="" class="center-block img-responsive">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

> You can Use only "md" Class Then media query apply

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="span4"></div>
        <div class="span4"><img class="center-block" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/></div>
      <div class="span4"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

> Learn about
>           Grid Classes
>           The Bootstrap grid system has four classes:
>
> ```
>     xs (for phones)
>     sm (for tablets)
>     md (for desktops)
>     lg (for larger desktops)
>
> The classes above can be combined to create more dynamic and flexible layouts.
> ```

**Use Class Your Purpose when your application display in which mode then apply Classs**

[Demo Link](http://jsfiddle.net/patelsumit5192/11bprycy/)